# Using CC BY ND 3.0 licensed icons in closed source project

Tags: cc-by-nd

I'm using icon sets provided by third party in a closed source project which might be distributed depending on the needs. All the icons will be bundled to the application.

As per my understanding, as long as I won't modify default downloaded PNGs, I'm good to go (As long as I provide a copy of license and attribute the author).

But is that assumption is correct? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Commons Deed at https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/ you just need to give credits and point out changes. But if you change the it, you may not redistribute it.

So you're correct